# How can I update the result set without removing the previous result from it

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using jdbc to retrieve data from database. I have four different queries for that, however, the result of first query is used to get the data of second and fourth query. But, the resultset, gets updated as i run other queries. So is there any way that i can keep the resultset and add new results in it.

Here is my code:

```
class GetData{

     String toDate;
     String fromDate;


        GetData(String d1,String d2) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ParseException, TransformerException, ParserConfigurationException  {

            toDate=d1;
            fromDate=d2;
            Connection connection= null;
            ResultSet resultset= null;

            String customerquery="SELECT o.ordernumber,o.orderdate,o.customernumber,c.customername,c.addressLine1,c.postalCode,c.city,c.country from orders o join customers c  on o.customernumber=c.customernumber where orderdate between ? and ?";
            String orderdetailquery="SELECT orderNumber,productCode,quantityOrdered,priceEach,orderLineNumber,(quantityOrdered * priceEach) as total FROM orderdetails where ordernumber=?";
            String productsquery="SELECT productName,productLine,productVendor FROM products where productcode=?";
            String employeequery="SELECT c.salesRepEmployeeNumber,e.firstname,e.lastname,o.officecode,o.city from customers c join employees e on c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = e.employeeNumber join offices o on e.officecode=o.officecode where c.customernumber=?";

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels","root","root");

            if(d1!=null || d2!=null) {

                PreparedStatement p1= connection.prepareStatement(customerquery);
                p1.setString(1, toDate);
                p1.setString(2,fromDate);
                resultset= p1.executeQuery();

                PreparedStatement p2= connection.prepareStatement(orderdetailquery);
                while(resultset.next()) {
                    p2.setString(1, resultset.getString("orderNumber"));
                }

                resultset=p2.executeQuery();

                PreparedStatement p3= connection.prepareStatement(productsquery);

                while (resultset.next()) {
                    p3.setString(1, resultset.getString("productcode"));
                }

                resultset=p3.executeQuery();

                PreparedStatement p4=connection.prepareStatement(employeequery);
                while(resultset.next()) {
                p4.setString(1, resultset.getString("customernumber"));
                }
                resultset=p4.executeQuery();

                resultset.close();
                connection.close();   
            }
        }
```

I am trying to use the result of first query that contains the column customernumber to fetch the data. While, executing the code a error comes that customernumber column not found. So, how can I use the result of first query in other queries. Also, i am trying to get all the result of queries in one resultset as I am trying to create a xml out of it by using DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put everything in a single `query`. using `joins`.

```
select o.ordernumber,o.orderdate
    , o.customernumber,c.customername
    , c.addressLine1,c.postalCode,c.city,c.country 
    , t1.productCode, t1.quantityOrdered, t1.priceEach, t1.orderLineNumber,(t1.quantityOrdered * t1.        priceEach) as total 
    , t2.productName, t2.productLine, t2.productVendor
    , c.salesRepEmployeeNumber,t4.firstname,t4.lastname,t3.officecode,t3.city
from orders o 
join customers c  on o.customernumber=c.customernumber 
left join orderdetails t1 on t1.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
left join products t2 on t2.productCode = t1.productCode
left join offices t3 on t3.offiecode = c.customernumber
left join employees t4 on t3.officecode = t4.officecode
```

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet is getting changed because you are using the same reference (object) every time you are executing the sql statement, hence it is overriding the old result, so if you want to deal with previously returned ResultSet, you can create new ResultSet instance to use, and also you can create a Bean class to set the elements and make it List type to keep on adding the results as per your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO to store required properties retrieved from different queries.
The resultset is getting updated because the same reference variable is being used to assign the resultset of subsequent queries.
If you want to use the same variable, you can follow like this -

1. create a POJO (which can be used to create a xml out of it by using DOM).
2. get result of first query in resultset.
3. populate relevant properties of POJO from this resultset.
4. re-use the resultset to store result of next queries.

When you need to use previous results, get them from the POJO to be used as parameters in subsequent queries.